# Timelapse Android App Image Sequence

Tags: time-lapse, android

Does anyone know a good timelapse app for Android, but one which records an actual image sequence, not a compressed video? (like Hyperlapse, Framelapse, and similar apps do)

So far I have only found Camera FV-5 to have this option, however, it just refuses to work on my phone (Nokia 6.1, Android 10) and won't record a single image.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Intervalometer" it works as an overlay app over your stock camera app. You can also try to do your own script with app like "Tasker".

BTW: Old version of Camera FV-5 worked too. Unfortunately they implemented a new UI, which doesn't work so well.